# The bounded sum is a primitive recursive function?

Tags: computer-science, computability

Let $f:\mathbb{N}^{p+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ a primitive recursive function and $g:\mathbb{N}^{p+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ the bounded sum defined by : $g(\bar{a},x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^x f(\bar a , i)$.

To show that $g$ is  a primitive recursive function we want to show that $g$ is closed under the primitive recursion :

$g(\bar a, 0)= f(\bar a ,0)= k(\bar a)$ where $k$ is a primitive recursive function because of $f$.

$g(\bar a, x+1) = g(\bar a , x) + f(\bar a,x+1)$ which is the sum of two recursive primitive functions (addition is also a recursive primitive operation).

But if we want to find explicitly a recursive primitive function $h$ such that : $g(\bar a, x+1) = h(\bar a, x ,g(\bar a, x))$ which $h$ should we take ?

I mean how can we make appear $f(\bar a , x+1)$ in $h$ ? As $f$ is primitive recursive we can write : $f(\bar a , x+1)= h'(\bar a, x, f(\bar a, x))$ hence $g(\bar a, x+1) = g(\bar a , x) + h'(\bar a, x, f(\bar a, x))$ but then I am stuck...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

When you say

$$g(\bar a, x+1) = g(\bar a , x) + f(\bar a,x+1)$$

is primitive recursive as it is the sum of two primitive recursive functions , you are assuming that $g(\bar a , \cdot)$ is a primitive recursive function, where I am using the $\cdot$ as a place-holder for the unknown argument of $g$. This doesn't work, because we are trying to show that $g(\bar a, \cdot)$ is primitive recursive and we don't have that as any kind of inductive hypothesis.

Instead, look at the desired relationship between $g(\bar a, x+1)$ and $g(\bar a , x)$, namely:

$$g(\bar a, x+1) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{x+1} f(\bar a , i) = g(\bar a, x) + f(\bar a, x +1)$$

So to get $g(\bar a, x+1) = g(\bar a , x) + f(\bar a,x+1)$ from the primitive recursion formula, what you need is:

$$h(\bar a, x, g(\bar a, x)) = g(\bar a, x) + f(\bar a, x+ 1)$$

But then if we think of $g(\bar a, x)$ as an unknown $y$, if we can find a primitive recursive $h$ such that :

$$h(\bar a, x, y) = y + f(\bar a, x+ 1)$$

we are done, because the above defines an $h$ that is primitive recursive if $f$ is (which is given), and combined with your approach to the function $k$ needed in the base case $x = 0$, you can prove by induction that the resulting primitive recursive function defined by $k$ and $h$ gives the sum $\sum\limits_{i=0}^x f(\bar a , i)$for all $\bar a$ and $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At the end, you replaced $g(\bar a , x)$ by $y$ ? The function $h$ can be written $add(\pi_{3}^{3}(\bar a,x,y),f(\bar a, x+1))$ ? With I have the feeling that we returned at the starting point ($g(\bar a,x)$ is not at that moment primitive recursive)...

Comment: I was trying to show you how to find $h$ working from the desired properties of $g$. Once you have found a likely candidate for $h$, you can then work the other way to show that the resulting primitive recursive function is equal to $g$. I have tried to make that clearer in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the details. I will still write $h(\bar a ,x,y) = add(\pi_{3}^{3}(\bar a,x,y),f(\bar a, x+1))$ which is a composition of recursive primitive functions.